# *cdkVirtualFor is not working in my application, it's in Angular 7.2.0

Tags: angular-material, angular7

```html
<ul class="list">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport  style="height: 500px" itemSize="90" >
      <div *ngFor="let n of numbers" style="height:130px;">{{n}}</div>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</ul>

<!--app.module.ts-->

import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ScrollingModule ]
})

<!--app.component.ts-->

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  numbers: number[] = [];

  constructor() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10000; index++) {
      this.numbers.push(index);
    }
  }
}
```

Everything is fine but its showing "=====>Can't bind to 'cdkVirtualForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.<=====" ERROR

Comment: What is the issue? Could you also post your css code?

Comment: Did you import `ScrollDispatchModule`?

Comment: yah imported already but it's showing that same error.

Comment: Can't bind to 'cdkVirtualForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Comment: So you should update your question with that information. On your question, the only module imported is `ScrollingModule `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should import ScrollingModule:

```
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
```

And add it into inports array in NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ScrollingModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Now add some styles to your div:

```
.example-viewport {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

.example-item {
    height: 50px;
}
```

It works for me) good luck)

Comment: Between Angular ver 7.3.7 and 8.1.4 _ScrollDispatchModule_ name was deprecated in favor of newer _ScrollingModule_

Comment: I had to import and export `ScrollingModule` in my shared module to remove the error.

Answer (score 9):

**Add below**

```
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
imports: [
    ScrollingModule
  ]
```

**Remove below**

```
import {CdkVirtualScrollViewport} from "@angular/cdk/scrolling";
imports: [
    CdkVirtualScrollViewport
  ]
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using `*ngFor` while you should be using `*cdkVirtualFor` as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview).

Try this code below:

```html
<ul class="list">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport  style="height: 500px" itemSize="90" >
      <div *cdkVirtualFor="let n of numbers" style="height:130px;">{{n}}</div>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the module should be registered.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

(Referred from https://pusher.com/tutorials/infinite-scrolling-angular-cdk)
use *cdkVirtualFor instead of ngFor

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you solved the problem.
In my case, the component trying to use `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>` was missing in the `declarations` part of the `app.module.ts` file.

A problem arose in an area that was not expected at all, and it was difficult to solve it.

I hope this solution to help you.

Comment: The `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` is part of CDK's `ScrollingModule` and should not independently be imported to one of your module's declarations.

Answer (score -3):

try this, it works for me.

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport  style="height: 500px" itemSize="90" >
  <ng-container *ngFor="let n of numbers" style="height:130px;">
    <div>{{n}}</div>
  </ng-container>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Comment: It's working like a regular list, not virtualized.

Comment: *cdkVirtualFor should be used in place of *ngFor